# Display Values based on dropdown selection MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I Get 500 internal error while want to get values of DDL in mvc 4 
it runs and give me the product id like bellow but doesnt show me the Porduct details:
http://localhost:24494/Merchant/GetProduct?id=14

**Controler:**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    ProductRepository BlProduct = new ProductRepository();
    var model = BlProduct.Find(id);
    return PartialView("_CampProductPartialView", model);
}
```

**Partial:**

```
@model CrazyAvocado.ViewModels.Merchant.AddCampaignViewModel

<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Product.Name)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.Price)
</div>
```

**view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCampaign", "Merchant", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myUploadForm" }))
```

**Dropdownlist:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Campaign.Productid, new SelectList(Model.Products, "id", "Name"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProductsDDL" })
```

**Div containing that should show details:**
Div id is "divPartialView"

```
@Html.Partial("_CampProductPartialView")
```

**And Finaly the Jquery Script**

```
<script>
  $("#ProductsDDL").change(function(event) {
    var ProductId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("
      GetProduct ", "
      Merchant ")",
      data: {
        id: ProductId
      },
      type: "Get",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        //Whatever result you have got from your controller
        // with html partial view replace with a specific html.
        $("#divPartialView").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Use your browser tools (Network tab) to insect the response - it will give you the details of the errror

Comment: Put a breakpoint after `var model = BlProduct.Find(id);` line and see if any proper data is assigned to model. Also check if you found any errors in browser console.